# How to replace PID controller with fuzzy controller so that it can work exactly the same as PID

Tags: simulink, pid-controller

I have a model in simulink as shown [image]

The model has PID controller with Kp=36 Kd=54 Ki=6. Pid controller is minimizing the error given as its input to zero. Now I want to replace it with fuzzy controller so that it exactly works the same as PID. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple ....
In Matlab workspace type *fuzzy* . Fuzzy toolbox will open. You are required to assign the Inputs and Outputs there. Make Error *e* and Change in error *de* as inputs nad *Kp* , *Ki*, and *Kd* as Outputs. Then decide the range for each of of the membership functions of these inputs and outputs. [Refer some research paper for details]

Save the model as *Model.fis* and export this model to workspace.

Open the Simulink and like as the figure you have posted replace it with Fuzzy Logic Controller Block and call the *Model.fis* in block. and run the simulation. :)